# Codeigniter Internal Server Error on redirect to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have the following function which is supposed to redirect to another page on success :

```
public function process() {


        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        // Validate the user can login

        $result = $this->login_model->validate($username, $password);
        // Now we verify the result
        if (!$result) {

            if (empty($password)) {
                $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
                $this->index($msg);
            } else {

                $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
                $this->index($msg);
            }
        } else {
            // If user did validate, 
            // Send them to members area
            redirect('home');
        }
    }
```

If it's valid ,then I should be redirected to the home but unfortunately I get the  following error :

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Internal Server Error

RequestURI=http://system.uniqueloo.co.ke/login/process
```

Is there another way I can do a redirect in codeigniter without using the  php redirect function?

Comment: Have you check htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

> **Make sure index function accepting incoming argument**

**In Controller**

```
public function process() {

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $result = $this->login_model->validate($username, $password);

    if (isset($result)) { #change this

        if (empty($password)) {

            $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
            $this->index($msg); # not sure about this
        } 
        else {

            $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
            $this->index($msg); # not sure about this
        }
    } 
    else {

        redirect('home');
    }
}
```